# Activate a javascript code when div is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Thank for the recomendations, I have updated my ask.

I have the next code:

https://jsfiddle.net/btq7mm0h/3/

Is a simply counter starts when the document is ready. I would like that it will start when the div id="testimonios" is visible on screen because when I do scroll to down for to see the effect is already can't see.

What I have made, I find several plugin js like

https://www.customd.com/articles/13/checking-if-an-element-is-visible-on-screen-using-jquery

Add script in my document and modified the code:

```
if $('#testimonios').visible( true ) {
   $('.count').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 9000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Please any suggestion.

Comment: Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Without the associated HTML, answers are likely to be just guesses.

Comment: Thanks for recomendation I have updated the ask.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to go about this such as using a timer, pure javascript and jquery has a few variations. Here's one way to go about this.

```
 $("#testimonios").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
   // do whatever here, you can even add an if statement for css such as
   var cssCheck = $(this).css('display');

   if (cssCheck == "block") {
    // Div Display is Visible
    alert("isVisible");
   } else {
    // Div Display is not Visible
    alert("isNotVisible");
   }
 });
```

You can see the result at codebin: http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqoyk

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it's not I searched. Simply I want a "trigger" when a div is visible on screen. I tried with isOnscreen, is visible, scrolltop but it don't work.

Comment: I'm confused on what you're asking? The code I provided acts "live" so at any time that div has any changes, it checks if it was the "display" and whether or not it is visible. The codebin elaborates on this with triggers. Make sure that you put this code either at the end of your page or on page load for it to work properly.